# Vaadin 7 send data from client to server

Tags: java, client, vaadin, rpc

I am struggling to apprehend the way `client` and `server` communicate in `vaadin 7`. I have understood it well when it comes to `server->client` communication, but I still I cannot grasp how it works the other way round, namely from client to server. I have read that on the client side one should not change the `State`, but they should send the relevant data through `rpc`. On the client side there is a `MyComponentClientRpc` inteface which contains some methods and the developer should implement them in the `Connector` class. Then one can instantiate the inteface as anonymous class on server and can call the method. However in case one has a String "myString" on client how can it be transfered to the server, since one can only call the method on server passing the parameters on the time of calling it? How can then one get the data lying on client?

```
public interface MyComponentClientRpc extends ClientRpc {

    public void getString(String s);

}  




public class MyComponentConnector extends AbstractComponentConnector {


    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    MyComponentClientRpc mcRpc = new MyComponentClientRpc() {
        public void getString(String s) {
            // TODO Do something useful
                ????
        }
    };

public MyComponentConnector() {
        registerRpc(MyComponentClientRpc.class, mcRpc);

String a = "myString";

....

}
```

In particular, how does one implement the method on client, how does one insert the data in it and how should it be called on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However in case one has a String "myString" on client how can it be
>   transfered to the server, since one can only call the method on server
>   passing the parameters on the time of calling it? How can then one get
>   the data lying on client?

You are using the wrong mechanism. There are actually two RPCs, `ClientRpc` and `ServerRpc`. In your example, you use `ClientRpc`, which is for calls from the server to the client.

To communicate from the client to the server, you have to extend from `ServerRpc`.

In the client, you call

```
 MyComponentClientRpc rpc = RpcProxy.create(MyComponentClientRpc.class, this)
```

in order to get the proxy.

Comment: I have examined it myself and finally I am persuaded that I should make sue of ServerRpc in this occasion as well, as you suggest. I should declare a method with a String parameter and pass the desired String as parameter to it, when calling in. Then in the implementation on the server side I get this String from the parameter. Am I right?